# Does NPOI support copying a worksheet and inserting it into the same workbook?

Tags: c#, .net, npoi, xssf

I'm new to using NPOI and the XSSF interfaces.

Does NPOI XSSF support copying a sheet and inserting it into the same workbook?

From reading, I see that through HSSF I can copy a sheet and insert it into a new workbook.

I know that Aspose.Cells supports this functionality.
Is this functionality available through NPOI XSSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy a sheet and insert it to the same workbook with the `CopyTo` method of an `XSSFSheet`. You need to make sure the copied sheet has a different name to avoid generating an exception.

Note that this method what introduced in [NPOI 2.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/).

Here's an example of copying the first sheet (at index 0) of a workbook:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0) as XSSFSheet;
sheet.CopyTo(workbook, $"{sheet.SheetName}_copy", true, true);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    workbook.Write(fs);
}
```